# How to change the effect of touches after a collision - sprite kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am quite new to Objective C and hope somebody can help me with my problem:

There's a character jumping to the right when I touch the display. If it touches the right side of the scene, it should change the direction and jump to the left every time I touch. Here is the code for jumping to the right:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {  
    [hero.physicsBody applyImpulse: CGVectorMake(10, 20)];  
}
```

(Should I even use the touchesBegan method?)

If the character touches the right side of the screen I need this:

```
[hero.physicsBody applyImpulse: CGVectorMake(-10, 20)];
```

The collision detection works perfectly, I just need to know how I can use these lines of code instead of the first ones when the program detects a collision. So where should I put both of these lines of code?

I hope you understand my dilemma and can help me...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can help you I just need some more information.  You want to jump when you touch the screen or you want the hero to endlessly jump until it hits a wall and turn to jump the other direction.  Basically, should the user control when the jumps occur by touch and the direction is determined by which wall the hero has hit last.

Comment: Yes, the hero should jump when I the user touches the screen and the direction is determined by which wall the hero has hit last. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL jumpRight;  //Yes = Right, No = Left
```

On collision with a wall, change the bool:

```
self.jumpRight = YES; or self.jumpRight = NO;
```

In touchesEnded:

```
if(self.jumpRight == YES)
[hero.physicsBody applyImpulse: CGVectorMake(10, 20)];
else
[hero.physicsBody applyImpulse: CGVectorMake(-10, 20)];
```

Should do the trick if your collision detection is set up :)

Comment: Just one more question...Once I touched one side of the screen I can change the direction, but it does not work one the other side (I keep jumping in the same direction). Where should I put the collision detection for the other side of the wall and the self.jumpDirection =YES; (or NO, just the other one)?

Comment: If your walls are set to have the same categoryBitMask which I assume they do:

     if(hero.position.x < self.size.width<2)
        self.jumpDirection=Yes;
      else
        self.jumpDirection=NO;

Comment: Just toggle the BOOL when you hit any wall with self.jumpDirection = !self.jumpDirection; BTW, wouldn't it be clearer if the property was called jumpRight?

Comment: Good call, made the name clearer. The code 0x141E posted above would do the trick with less code.

Comment: @CSSLink Would you mind marking this as answered if it resolved your main problem?  This way other people with the same problem can quickly find a solution.  Thanks!